# Blur is fired twice when the entire page is blured in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic `textarea`s in the web page that are added by jQuery and I have to detect the `blur` event for them.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpRgf/);

The following code work fine until the entire page is blured (move to another tab, alt-tab press etc) when the blur event is called two times.

```
// I've already tried with another selector, parent of the textareas
// instead of document, but it's the same result.
$(document).on("blur", "textarea", function () {
    $("body").append("<br />Blured the " + (($(this).index() / 2) + 1) + " textarea.");
});
```

I am looking for a solution using only `on` function this way and **not** like bellow (in this case the issue exists too):

```
var element = $("<textarea></textarea><br />");

element.on("blur", function () {
    $("body").append("<br />Blured the " + (($(this).index() / 2) + 1) + " textarea.");
});

...
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpRgf/1/);

So the issue is that when the textarea is focused and the page is blured the blur event is fired twice.

Which is the solution for this?

Is this a browser issue? How to prevent it?

**Update:** It seems that it is present only in **Google Chrome**.

OS: Ubuntu 13.04

---

I've reported the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253253

Comment: The blur event is always triggered when the element looses focus, which it of course does if it has focus and you go to another tab.

Comment: @adeneo ya but here it is fired twice, so why?

Comment: This works for me perfectly. I've tried in chrome. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @speti43 focus the textarea, write something, move the tab without bluring the textarea, move again to the jsfiddle tab and see the **messages** appended. I see two messages appended in Chrome and one in Firefox. This means that blur event was fired two times in Chrome but 1 time in Firefox.

Comment: Ok, I see, very interesting behavior.

Comment: Will you create a ticket? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @Jonathan Good idea. I will create soon.

Comment: @Jonathan Posted it here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253253

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other possible workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/tpRgf/4/

```
(function () {
    var lastActive;
    $(document).on("blur", "textarea", function () {
        if (lastActive === this) { return; }
            lastActive = this;
            $("body").append("<br />Blured the " + (($(this).index() / 2) + 1) + " textarea.");

    }).on('focus', "textarea", function () {
        lastActive = null;
    });
})();
```

Comment: I would preffer `if (lastActive === this) { return; }`.

Comment: I've chosen this method finally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can use a timeout to make sure the event isn't fired twice :

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("#test").append("<textarea></textarea><br />");
});

$(document).on("blur", "textarea", function () {
    var self = $(this);
    if (! self.data('fired')) {
        $("body").append("<br />Blured the " + (($(this).index() / 2) + 1) + " textarea.");
    }
    self.data('fired', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.data('fired', false);
    },0);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpRgf/3/)

Comment: Oh, didn't get it, I thought the point was to not fire the blur event when leaving the page, but you're saying it fires twice, and you only want it to fire once, but for me it only fires once, so there doesn't seem to be an issue ?

Comment: I've got same issue as OP, but looks like you are not the only one who doesn't have any issue, see speti43's comment

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I want to fire it only one time. What browser and OS do you use? I am on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but this isn't the best way I think. What if in that timeout another correct blur is fired?

Comment: It's set at 0.1 seconds, and you can even change that to zero and it would work, it's just about deferring really, and the browser will in most cases use 0.05 seconds as a minimum, and there's no way you can focus and blur the textarea within that time anyway.

Comment: @adeneo thanks, but I accept the roasted answer. I've chosen his solution. Voting this too. :-)